# How to change connection into pending state? Reactor Netty

Tags: netty, reactor-netty

Hi I'm very new to Reactor Netty.

I'm trying to transfer via TCP protocol by using connection pool.
So, I built ConnectionProvider when the application starts and give it to TcpClient as an argument.

```
  @PostConstructpublic void init() {     
    provider = ConnectionProvider.builder("fixed")            
                .maxConnections(20)            
                .pendingAcquireMaxCount(200)            
                .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))            
                .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(10))            
                .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20))       
                .build();
  } 

public void send(String ip, int port, String logText) {    
    TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create(provider)            
                          .host(ip)            
                          .port(port);    
    tcpClient.connect().subscribe(connection -> {        
              System.out.println("connection : " + connection);       
              connection.outbound().sendString(Mono.just(logText)).then().subscribe();           
    });
}
```

After sending 20 times, the application throws

```
PoolAcquireTimeoutException:Pool#acquire(Duration has been pending for more than the configured timeout of 20000ms
```

If I remove .pendingAcquireMaxCount(200) and .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20)) when building Connection Provider, it throws

```
PoolAcquirePendingLimitException: pending acquire queue has reached its maximum size of 40
```

I guess it's because Connection is not returned to the pool properly.

How can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

You can set the pending connections request to have no limit when the connection pool is fully used using `-1` as the value of `pendingAcquireMaxCount` configuration's builder property:

```java
provider = ConnectionProvider.builder("fixed")
     .maxConnections(20)
     .pendingAcquireMaxCount(-1) // no limits on pending connection requests
     .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(10)) // you should better increase the max-idle value as well        
     .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20))       
     .build();
```